# Problem with multiple Parallax PING))) Ultrasonic Sensors

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm trying to make an AGV(automated guided vehicle) which I wanna use 4 parallax ultrasonic sensors for but there is a problem when I'm using 1 of them its all okay and works perfectly fine, but when I add 1 or more my output on serial monitor says 0cm. I just can't figure it out

I have read lots of forums already but nothing works yet. Here is the code I'm using for 1:

```
// this constant won't change. It's the pin number of the sensor's output:
const int pingPin = 7;

void setup() {
  // initialize serial communication:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // establish variables for duration of the ping, and the distance result
  // in inches and centimeters:
  long duration, inches, cm;

  // The PING))) is triggered by a HIGH pulse of 2 or more microseconds.
  // Give a short LOW pulse beforehand to ensure a clean HIGH pulse:
  pinMode(pingPin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(pingPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(pingPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(5);
  digitalWrite(pingPin, LOW);

  // The same pin is used to read the signal from the PING))): a HIGH pulse
  // whose duration is the time (in microseconds) from the sending of the ping
  // to the reception of its echo off of an object.
  pinMode(pingPin, INPUT);
  duration = pulseIn(pingPin, HIGH);

  // convert the time into a distance
  inches = microsecondsToInches(duration);
  cm = microsecondsToCentimeters(duration);

  Serial.print(inches);
  Serial.print("in, ");
  Serial.print(cm);
  Serial.print("cm");
  Serial.println();

  delay(100);
}

long microsecondsToInches(long microseconds) {
  // According to Parallax's datasheet for the PING))), there are 73.746
  // microseconds per inch (i.e. sound travels at 1130 feet per second).
  // This gives the distance travelled by the ping, outbound and return,
  // so we divide by 2 to get the distance of the obstacle.
  // See: http://www.parallax.com/dl/docs/prod/acc/28015-PING-v1.3.pdf
  return microseconds / 74 / 2;
}

long microsecondsToCentimeters(long microseconds) {
  // The speed of sound is 340 m/s or 29 microseconds per centimeter.
  // The ping travels out and back, so to find the distance of the object we
  // take half of the distance travelled.
  return microseconds / 29 / 2;
}
```

And here when I use more than 1

```
// this constant won't change. It's the pin number of the sensor's output:
const int pingPin = 7;
const int pingPin2 = 6;
const int pingPin3 = 5;
const int pingPin4 = 4;

void setup() {
  // initialize serial communication:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // establish variables for duration of the ping, and the distance result
  // in inches and centimeters:
  long duration, inches, cm;

  // The PING))) is triggered by a HIGH pulse of 2 or more microseconds.
  // Give a short LOW pulse beforehand to ensure a clean HIGH pulse:
  pinMode(pingPin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(pingPin, LOW);
  digitalWrite(pingPin2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(pingPin3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(pingPin4, LOW);

  delayMicroseconds(2);

  digitalWrite(pingPin, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(pingPin2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(pingPin3, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(pingPin4, HIGH);

  delayMicroseconds(5);

  digitalWrite(pingPin, LOW);
  digitalWrite(pingPin2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(pingPin3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(pingPin4, LOW);

  // The same pin is used to read the signal from the PING))): a HIGH pulse
  // whose duration is the time (in microseconds) from the sending of the ping
  // to the reception of its echo off of an object.
  pinMode(pingPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(pingPin2, INPUT);
  pinMode(pingPin3, INPUT);
  pinMode(pingPin4, INPUT);

  duration = pulseIn(pingPin, HIGH);
  duration = pulseIn(pingPin2, HIGH);
  duration = pulseIn(pingPin3, HIGH);
  duration = pulseIn(pingPin4, HIGH);

  // convert the time into a distance
  inches = microsecondsToInches(duration);
  cm = microsecondsToCentimeters(duration);

  Serial.print(inches);
  Serial.print("in, ");
  Serial.print(cm);
  Serial.print("cm");
  Serial.println();

  delay(100);
}

long microsecondsToInches(long microseconds) {
  // According to Parallax's datasheet for the PING))), there are 73.746
  // microseconds per inch (i.e. sound travels at 1130 feet per second).
  // This gives the distance travelled by the ping, outbound and return,
  // so we divide by 2 to get the distance of the obstacle.
  // See: http://www.parallax.com/dl/docs/prod/acc/28015-PING-v1.3.pdf
  return microseconds / 74 / 2;
}

long microsecondsToCentimeters(long microseconds) {
  // The speed of sound is 340 m/s or 29 microseconds per centimeter.
  // The ping travels out and back, so to find the distance of the object we
  // take half of the distance travelled.
  return microseconds / 29 / 2;
}
```

when I use 1 sensor it gives me the right values like expected and when I use 2 or more sensors the a value of 0cm

Comment: You have triggered them at once and then measure time time one by one. Trigger the next one only after echo time from previous one has been measured. Also I recommend to add extra pause before run measurement on the next sensor to get rid of possible late echo from the previous sensor.

Comment: thank you as show down here in my answer the new sketch how i fixed the problem :D

Answer (score -1):

thanks i just copy paste the code for a single sensor 4 times after each other and made each of them for another sensor there is just a small delay in each sensor but thats alright. new code is as following:

```
// this constant won't change. It's the pin number of the sensor's output:
const int pingPin = 7;
const int pingPin2= 6;
const int pingPin3 = 5;
const int pingPin4 = 4;

void setup() {
  // initialize serial communication:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // establish variables for duration of the ping, and the distance result
  // in inches and centimeters:
  long duration, inches, cm;

  // The PING))) is triggered by a HIGH pulse of 2 or more microseconds.
  // Give a short LOW pulse beforehand to ensure a clean HIGH pulse:
  pinMode(pingPin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(pingPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(pingPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(5);
  digitalWrite(pingPin, LOW);

  // The same pin is used to read the signal from the PING))): a HIGH pulse
  // whose duration is the time (in microseconds) from the sending of the ping
  // to the reception of its echo off of an object.
  pinMode(pingPin, INPUT);
  duration = pulseIn(pingPin, HIGH);

  // convert the time into a distance
  inches = microsecondsToInches(duration);
  cm = microsecondsToCentimeters(duration);

  Serial.print(inches);
  Serial.print("in, "); 
  Serial.print(cm);
  Serial.print("cm");
  Serial.println();

  delay(400);

  // The PING))) is triggered by a HIGH pulse of 2 or more microseconds.
  // Give a short LOW pulse beforehand to ensure a clean HIGH pulse:
  pinMode(pingPin2, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(pingPin2, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(pingPin2, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(5);
  digitalWrite(pingPin2, LOW);

  // The same pin is used to read the signal from the PING))): a HIGH pulse
  // whose duration is the time (in microseconds) from the sending of the ping
  // to the reception of its echo off of an object.
  pinMode(pingPin2, INPUT);
  duration = pulseIn(pingPin2, HIGH);

  // convert the time into a distance
  inches = microsecondsToInches(duration);
  cm = microsecondsToCentimeters(duration);

  Serial.print(inches);
  Serial.print("in, "); 
  Serial.print(cm);
  Serial.print("cm");
  Serial.println();

  delay(400);


  // The PING))) is triggered by a HIGH pulse of 2 or more microseconds.
  // Give a short LOW pulse beforehand to ensure a clean HIGH pulse:
  pinMode(pingPin3, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(pingPin3, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(pingPin3, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(5);
  digitalWrite(pingPin3, LOW);

  // The same pin is used to read the signal from the PING))): a HIGH pulse
  // whose duration is the time (in microseconds) from the sending of the ping
  // to the reception of its echo off of an object.
  pinMode(pingPin3, INPUT);
  duration = pulseIn(pingPin3, HIGH);

  // convert the time into a distance
  inches = microsecondsToInches(duration);
  cm = microsecondsToCentimeters(duration);

  Serial.print(inches);
  Serial.print("in, "); 
  Serial.print(cm);
  Serial.print("cm");
  Serial.println();

  delay(400);

  // The PING))) is triggered by a HIGH pulse of 2 or more microseconds.
  // Give a short LOW pulse beforehand to ensure a clean HIGH pulse:
  pinMode(pingPin4, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(pingPin4, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(pingPin4, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(5);
  digitalWrite(pingPin4, LOW);

  // The same pin is used to read the signal from the PING))): a HIGH pulse
  // whose duration is the time (in microseconds) from the sending of the ping
  // to the reception of its echo off of an object.
  pinMode(pingPin4, INPUT);
  duration = pulseIn(pingPin4, HIGH);

  // convert the time into a distance
  inches = microsecondsToInches(duration);
  cm = microsecondsToCentimeters(duration);

  Serial.print(inches);
  Serial.print("in, "); 
  Serial.print(cm);
  Serial.print("cm");
  Serial.println();

  delay(400);
}

long microsecondsToInches(long microseconds) {
  // According to Parallax's datasheet for the PING))), there are 73.746
  // microseconds per inch (i.e. sound travels at 1130 feet per second).
  // This gives the distance travelled by the ping, outbound and return,
  // so we divide by 2 to get the distance of the obstacle.
  // See: http://www.parallax.com/dl/docs/prod/acc/28015-PING-v1.3.pdf
  return microseconds / 74 / 2;
}

long microsecondsToCentimeters(long microseconds) {
  // The speed of sound is 340 m/s or 29 microseconds per centimeter.
  // The ping travels out and back, so to find the distance of the object we
  // take half of the distance travelled.
  return microseconds / 29 / 2;
}
```